# Nagata's bizzare examples

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Hi,

due to Nagata and his clever and bizzare examples I'm unsure in this:

1) Is there a regular ring of infinite Krull dimension?

2) Is it true that: Regular ring of finite Krull dimension = Commutative Noetherian ring of finite global dimension? (answer is yes if R is local by Serre's Theorem)

Regards,
David

Answer (score 9):

For 1), Nagata's counterexample goes as follows:

Let $\mathbb{N}=A_1\cup A_2 \cup \cdots$ be a partition such that $|A_i|<|A_{i+1}|$. Take $S=k[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$, prime ideals $I_i=\langle x_i | i\in A_i \rangle$ and consider the localization $S[U^{-1}]$ in the multiplcative set $U=S \setminus \bigcup_i I_i$. Then the height of each of the $I_i$ is $|A_i|$ and so $S[U^{-1}]$ has infinite Krull dimension. It not so hard to show that the ring is regular, but a more surprising point is that it is also Noetherian.

For 2) I believe the answer is yes by this [reference](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rTTS6seRfSIC&lpg=PA51&dq=finite%2520Krull%2520dimension%2520%2520finite%2520global%2520dimension&pg=PA51#v=onepage&q=finite%2520Krull%2520dimension%2520%2520finite%2520global%2520dimension&f=false).

Comment: And why is this noetherian?

Comment: The ring is in fact noetherian, but showing this is non-trivial (for a reference, see Nagata's original paper). I edited my answer above.